# Global planner with curvature limit

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, teb-local-planner, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm looking for a **global** path planner (base_global_planner) with a feature of limiting the curvature (or turning radius) of the path.
I found teb_local_planner which can configure the minimum turning radius, but it's designed as a local planner.

Does anyone knows a path planner compatible with curvature limitation?
Or, is there a way to use teb_local_planner as a global planner, just for publishing the entire path to the goal?

My environment: Ubuntu 18.04, ROS Melodic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388632/global-planner-with-curvature-limit/) by [mit](https://answers.ros.org/users/87234/mit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-14**:
Hi @mit pls take a look at this previous question: #q234821

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-14**:
There is a nice explanation and a link to a tutorial

**Comment by [mit](https://answers.ros.org/users/87234/mit/) on 2021-10-14**:
@osilva Thanks for the information, but I think that is not I want to do.
Both the explanation and tutorial assume that we have a pre-generated global path, but I need a way to get a global path considering its maximum curvature.
Actually I'm planning to use a self-made local planner rather than teb_local_planner, so a global planner with curvature limiting feature is my ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not one in the well-maintained or core nav stacks in ROS 1.

However, there is one for ROS 2 in the Smac Planner, the Hybrid-A* planner https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-smac-planner.html

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mit](https://answers.ros.org/users/87234/mit/) on 2021-10-16**:
Thank you @stevemacenski, I will try that

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-10-16**:
Can you accept the answer to get off the unanswered queue?